# Can you disable automatic mdadm startup?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I am creating a RAID 10 array over four iSCSI targets.  I want to control everything manually though so I can run it through heartbeat.  I've unlinked the open-iscsi and mdadm scripts from /etc/rc#.d/ but the raid array is still recreated on boot up.  Once the server boots up I have to do a mdadm --stop /dev/md0 and then /etc/init.d/mdadm stop to make sure it doesn't fire it up again.  I commented out my array from /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf but it just created a new one later.  How can I put mdadm into a manual process so it only attempts to start or rebuild the array when I tell it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

```
   # by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
   # alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
  DEVICE partitions
```

what about scan something like /dev/null ? I mean some devices without superblocks. So mdadm cant find arrays.

Comment: DEVICE /dev/null does not work - for anyone who reads this later, don't bother, mdadm will still auto-assemble

Answer (score 3):

From a RHEL 6.7 setup adding `AUTO -all` in `/etc/mdadm.conf` to disable all auto-assembly, except for ARRAYs/DEVICEs otherwise specified, seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked for me was (see `man mdadm.conf`):

```
# /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
ARRAY <ignore> UUID=xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what flavour of Linux you are using (I'm assuming Linux?). You can control startup behaviour on debian/ubuntu with

```
dpkg-reconfigure mdadm
```

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04.  I tried that and the only startup it asks about is the monitor which I had already turned off.

Answer (score -1):

let me share my solution, just uninstall mdadm from your system. the uninstall script will auto trigger hook for update ramfs.

> apt remove mdadm

Comment: The question asked specifically how to disable *automatic* array startup, and the intention was to be able to start it manually, which your suggestion will preclude.